# How can I change the pivot of a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am currently working on a Project for the HoloLens2. 
But currently I am stuck. I want to create a chest like Item, with a lid.

But currently I'm not able to rotate tge GameObject on the hinge with these components: 
- Box Collider
- Manipulation Handler
- Near Interaction Grabbable

In the inspector i can Rotate the Object arount its pivot.

But i wasn't able to add the controlls with the HoloLens2 MRTK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pivot is not a real thing that exists.  The pivot is just the origin of the local coordinate system.  Armed with this knowledge, there are two ways to move the pivot.

1) Move all the vertices (or the pivot) in your 3d modeling application.

2) parent your geometry to an empty game object, and use this new parent to rotate around.

[image: Parent transform]

[image: Lid Transform]

[image: lid demo]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. That i know, but i dont know how to handle it with the HoloLens and its Handcontrolls..

Comment: Use a physics hinge for the hinge joint, and then for the hand controls, dynamically add a fixed or spring joint between the controller's gameobject and the thing they are grabbing.

Comment: Sorry that was vive-speak.  In hololens I think you need to make an empty Near Interaction Grabbable and attach it to the end of the lid with a spring joint.  And then after manipulation ends, reset the grabbable's position back onto the lid.

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip! That helped me alot. Already build a protoype with a Cube and Spring Joint! Works perfiktly